# How to set a code to automatically add today's date to a filename?

Tags: r, replace, automation, scheduled-tasks

Every day I have to change a date "YYMMDD" manually then run a code. I would like to find a way to make this change automatically. So I can just run the code without having to manually enter today's date.

In the example below I try to read in the file on june 12th, 2017.

```
task<- read.csv("\pattern~file_170612.txt", sep = " ", header=F, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: See `?Sys.Date`

Comment: This question is really not clear.  Presumably you could use Sys.date() but where is it that you want to use it?

Comment: I edited your question to make a bit more clear what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

If it's today's date you need:

- `Sys.Date()` to get today's date
- `strftime()` or similar to get it in a correct format. `%y%m%d` means "year in 2 digits, month in 2 digits, day in 2 digits" (see `?strftime` ). If you need year in 4 digits, use `%Y` instead of `%y`.
- `paste0()` to create the filename

a short example:

```
thedate <- strftime(Sys.Date(),"%y%m%d")
thefile <- paste0("/pattern~file_",thedate,".txt")
thefile
# [1] "/pattern~file_170613.txt"
```

On a sidenote: using backward slashes for file paths is not the best idea in R. You better use forward slashes.